# how to use spring data mongodb and spring cloud together

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud

I am now using this POM to

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>
```

to include both spring data mongodb and spring cloud together in a same project. But now, I need to upgrade spring data mongoDB, and this is the POM parent config that I need:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Now the problem happened, I still need to keep spring cloud,based on my understanding, I can have only one parent in the pom configuration, so I have to keep spring-cloud-starter-parent, and that should contains spring-boot-starter-parent already. May I ask which version of spring-cloud-starter-parent is equivalent to spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.1.RELEASE?

I changed to 1.3.7.RELEASE, and got error msg like this in my IDE:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.test:ngcsc-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-
     parent:pom:1.3.7.RELEASE in https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted 
     until the update interval of cloudera has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

so what shall I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring cloud can be used with the Spring Boot parent.

As you can see here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/
So this should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Spring Boot</artifactId>
    <name>Mongo</name>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```